# Zookeeper TLS setup using PEM file

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache-zookeeper, pem

I see zookeeper 3.5.5 has a option to pass in .PEM files to set up TLS encryption. 
I have server certificate.pem and privatekey.pem generated using openssl and set zookeper config as below

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=10.247.246.3:2888:3888
server.2=10.247.246.4:2888:3888
server.3=10.247.246.5:2888:3888

sslQuorum=true
serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
ssl.quorum.keyStore.location=/tmp/zoo/apache-zookeeper-3.5.7-bin/bin/certs/test/certWithPrivateKey.pem
ssl.quorum.keyStore.password=********
ssl.quorum.trustStore.location=/path/to/ca/ca-cert.pem
ssl.quorum.trustStore.password=******
ssl.hostnameVerification=false
ssl.quorum.hostnameVerification=false
ssl.keyStore.type=PEM
ssl.quorum.keyStore.type=PEM
ssl.trustStore.type=PEM
ssl.quorum.trustStore.type=PEM
```

But I get this error when starting zookeeper.

```
org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Exception$SSLContextException: Failed to create KeyManager
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createSSLContextAndOptionsFromConfig(X509Util.java:350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createSSLContextAndOptions(X509Util.java:328)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createSSLContextAndOptions(X509Util.java:282)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.getDefaultSSLContextAndOptions(X509Util.java:262)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createSSLSocket(X509Util.java:517)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:672)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:748)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:776)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:958)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:1425)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Exception$KeyManagerException: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 111
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createKeyManager(X509Util.java:447)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createSSLContextAndOptionsFromConfig(X509Util.java:348)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 111
        at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:95)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.util.PemReader.loadPrivateKey(PemReader.java:154)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.util.PemReader.loadPrivateKey(PemReader.java:142)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.util.PemReader.loadKeyStore(PemReader.java:103)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.PEMFileLoader.loadKeyStore(PEMFileLoader.java:50)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.loadKeyStore(X509Util.java:400)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util.createKeyManager(X509Util.java:436)
```

Note : I checked zookeeper source code [PEMReader.java](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/util/PemReader.java), as the code was expecting key and cert to be in PEM file .
I have created certWithPrivate.pem by concatenating certificate.pem and privatekey.pem (cat certificate.pem privatekey.pem > certWithPrivate.pem)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Private key was not encrypted , removing passwords(ssl.quorum.keyStore.password & ssl.quorum.trustStore.password ) worked .

ref: [Exception when Constructing EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580958/exception-when-constructing-encryptedprivatekeyinfo)